# How do I resolve the error "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length" in apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am getting the following error on a site I've just setup in Apache 2:

> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

The fixes I've seen around suggest that a fix is to be sure the default-ssl site is enabled, which I have done, but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 26):

That usually means that you are sending a HTTPS request to a HTTP service. The message is from the browser complaining that it was unable to to complete the SSL handshake that it was expecting.

do you have

`SSLEngine on`

configured for that vhost?

Comment: I've found a thread on StackOverflow that solved the problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl.  Specifically, changing my default-ssl config from <VirtualHost 123.456.789.0:443> to <VirtualHost _default_:443>

Comment: you probably need to post your vhost config `apachectl -S
`, and also the output from `netstat -lntp` (this is linux right?)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get this error if your virtual host configuration is incomplete and relies on `ssl.conf` (vendor installed) to do the setup for you. For example if you have a something like this (RHEL7/httpd 2.4):

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/confluence.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  localhost.localdomain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/html/index.html**

```
helo
```

Then because `confluence.conf` is alphabetically before `ssl.conf`, the SSL virtual host will not yet have been evaluated and httpd will use port 443 to serve unencrypted data, which you can prove like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl https://localhost.localdomain 
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
[root@localhost ~]# curl http://localhost.localdomain:443   
helo
```

In this case we can see the second `curl` works because the connection on port 443 is speaking plain `http`.

If we rename `confluence.conf` to be alphabetically after `ssl.conf`, then the SSL port will have been setup and it all starts working, eg:

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# curl https://localhost.localdomain -k
curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
[root@localhost vagrant]# mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/confluence.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/t.conf         
[root@localhost vagrant]# systemctl restart httpd
[root@localhost vagrant]# curl https://localhost.localdomain -k
helo
```

My recommendation to fix this would be to configure `mod_ssl` within the `VirtualHost` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Alternatively, renaming the file containing the `VirtualHost` definition to come alphabetically after `ssl.conf` will will work but this technique can be easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Re: changing from `<VirtualHost 123.456.789.0:443>` to `<VirtualHost default:443>`, I found exactly the opposite w/Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS6; when I changed from `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` to `<VirtualHost 123.456.789.0:443>`;

I received an error at Apache restart:

> [error] VirtualHost 123.456.789.0:443 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

yet the cert was served and once an exception was applied the site loaded.

It's all frelling magic...

Answer (score 0):

[a before-after of my .cfg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PntMu.png)
I had this problem, and eventually figured it out to work in my situation.

What I changed:

- Defaults: mode & option.
- Frontend: bind & stats uri (I had a typo).
- Backend: changed :80 to :443 (this is where my problem was).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another cause of this problem: Apache configured for SSL and listening on port 443, but **Apache mod_ssl not installed!**

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was different, but make sure the VirtualHost is configured for port 443, not port 80.