# SSL configuration issue - "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length"

Tags: ssl, https, wordpress, apache2

We are trying to setup SSL on our application running on Wordpress, PHP, Apache. After doing the necessary configuration changes, we get the following error on curl command -

```
[root@www ~]# curl https://www.<domain name> -v
* About to connect() to www.<domain name> port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.1.5...
* Connected to www.<domain name> (<domain IP>) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/sql/pki/nssdb
* CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* CApath: none
* NSS error -12263 (SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG)
* SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
* Closing connection 0
* curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
[root@www ~]#
```

We noticed the .crt file name here (`/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`) is different from what we have set in the SSL config file -  `/etc/pki/tls/certs/<domain name>.crt`.

**We followed these steps -**

- Found the effective httpd.conf file using `ps aux | grep httpd`
- Configured `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKey` in `apache/conf/ssl.conf` -

https://freeimage.host/i/UQ6Zxt

- Made changes to httpd.conf -

  Listen 443

  ServerName `www.<domain name>:443`
- Restarted httpd service.

Also checked that PHP configurations shows the following on `phpinfo()` output -

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
openssl
Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
```

On checking this file, we found -

```
[ CA_default ]

dir             = /etc/pki/CA           # Where everything is kept
certs           = $dir/certs            # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir         = $dir/crl              # Where the issued crl are kept
database        = $dir/index.txt        # database index file.
#unique_subject = no                    # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                                        # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts         # default place for new certs.

certificate     = $dir/cacert.pem       # The CA certificate
serial          = $dir/serial           # The current serial number
crlnumber       = $dir/crlnumber        # the current crl number
                                        # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl             = $dir/crl.pem          # The current CRL
private_key     = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE        = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file
```

Here as well, I don't see the .pem and .crt files that are being referenced in the curl output, so I am clueless.

I have checked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/379772/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-perm) as well and verified Open ssl extension loaded using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php.

The network/server administration team that provided the above details said that something configured at Wordpress end could be causing this scenario. Do you think this makes sense?

**Update**

Following is also set on ssl.conf file of Apache -

```
SSLEngine on
```

Also, following is the entire ssl.conf file (removing all commented lines) -

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName www.<domain name>:443
ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
LogLevel warn
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/<domain name>.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/<domain name>.key
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This error is common when trying to reach a site via SSL which is not SSL enabled. It has nothing to do with the certificate. While the configuration info for your server is incomplete you might have missed to set `SSLEngine on` for the listener on port 443. Note that the PHP info are irrelevant here too - they are only relevant when you want to make HTTPS calls from inside your server side backend of the web application to other systems.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I checked `SSLEngine on` is also specified in ssl.conf file. Added same to Update on question.